# CSS navbar border

Tags: html, css, flask, navbar

I'm new to HTML and trying to build a website using Flask.
I want to make my bar like the one on the picture, but this site writes the bar as a table and I am not allowed to nor know how to.
I can't find any way to create a border at the sides of each box (image attached).
What should I write in both the CSS and the HTML?
Thanks.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBqaI.jpg)

Comment: can you share your code..

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help when you haven't shared any code but if I were to do it from scratch I would do something like this.

```css
.navbar {
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar ul li 
{
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#first {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="first">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Three</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>Four</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```